# Filezilla client and VSFTPD : GnuTLS error -12: A TLS fatal alert has been received

Tags: ftp, ftps, vsftpd

so right now i'am trying to configure vsftpd server for FTP(e)S. 
It seems i am encountering issues with different clients. 
Secure FTPD works fine for me. 
Filezilla not.

The output from Filezilla

```
tatus:  Connecting to foo:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive() 
Response:   220 "Welcome to FTP!"
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Command:    AUTH TLS
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   234 Proceed with negotiation.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Trace:  CTlsSocket::Handshake()
Trace:  CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
Trace:  CTlsSocket::OnSend()
Trace:  CTlsSocket::OnRead()
Trace:  CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
Trace:  CTlsSocket::Failure(-12, 53)
Trace:  GnuTLS alert 40: Handshake failed
Error:  GnuTLS error -12: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
```

Paste from vsftpd:

```
# Could be whatever you like, or 990 if you want to use the now-deprecated ftps port.
listen_port=21

# Limit passive ports to this range to assis firewalling
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=30003

#May be needed to help packets through some NAT/firewall setups. The address
# is the external ip of the machine, assuming it is a static one.
pasv_address= "foo" ---> we NAT everything so this has the EXTERNAL IP

# Set to ssl_enable=YES if you want to enable SSL
ssl_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
anon_root=/srv/ftp
anon_upload_enable=NO
idle_session_timeout=900
log_ftp_protocol=YES
pasv_enable=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
ssl_tlsv1=YES

# Path to the certificate and key files (which should be the same file)
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd2.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/vsftpd2.pem

# No ssl for bad boys
#allow_anon_ssl=NO

# All local logins (i.e. non-anonymous) are forced to use ssl.
force_local_data_ssl=NO
#force_local_logins_ssl=YES
#dsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd.pem
require_ssl_reuse=NO
```

So question is: what goes wrong here? 
BTW: I am furthermore not completely sure what the difference is between ftps and ftpEs

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, found it. Apparently there is some strange behavior between the latest filezilla 3.5 client and ftps.

for vsftpd, the solution was simply to add: ssl_ciphers=HIGH in the vsftpd.conf file

I'am not sure whether i am allowed to post this as well, but there is a threat about this in the filezilla forums.

http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=23280

Comment: I know it's 2 years later, but i'm having this problem now but do not appear to have a file located in "/etc/vsftpd.conf".

Answer (score 0):

If `chroot_local_user=yes` is used then `ssl_ciphers=HIGH` wont work.